# Trouble with storing data into session

Tags: php, session

I'm using ajax to send data from card.php to adapter.php. Onclick invokes function and ajax is sending data to adapter.php using POST method.
In adapter.php I have a case:

```
        case 'buyCard':
        $order=array();
        $id=$_POST['id'];
        $quantity=$_POST['quantity'];
        $price=$_POST['price']; 
        $order['id']=$id;
        $order['quantity']=$quantity; 
        $order['price']=$price;

        $index=$_SESSION['orders_count']++;
        $_SESSION[$index]['orders']=$order;

        while($index){
            var_dump($_SESSION[$index]['orders']);
            $index--;
        }
        break;
```

And if I click on button that invokes that function few times, the result (inspected using `var_dump`) is pretty much like:

```
"array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["quantity"]=> string(0) "" ["price"]=> string(1) "8" } NULL NULL NULL NULL".
```

Please help.

Comment: so what is your problem exactly???

Comment: In the result you can see NULL values, and every of that NULL represents click on the button. Problem is that $_SESSION stores only last click/last value...

Comment: Also in your code `$_SESSION['orders_count']` is used? where this one defined and declared? in your code i dint see its declaration anywhere?

Comment: Be sure to update the `orders_count` in your session otherwise you are overwriting the same `index` over and over

Comment: Session is started and  orders_count is declared outside this case...

Comment: `$index=$_SESSION['orders_count']++; $_SESSION['orders_count'] = $index;` add the second line and check.

Comment: @A-2-A That will actually make sure that it never increases :-) The OP probably needs `$index = ++$_SESSION['orders_count'];` if anything because now the first order will be discarted, at least in the `var_dump`. See for example: https://eval.in/507467

Comment: There are still NULL values...